# Error regarding creating a jar file : Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a already built in code for logistic regression using Apache spark Scala. Now i am going create a jar file from this using IntelliJ IDEA. But i am getting some errors .

First I imported the data using a CSV file. Then i fitted a logistic regression model. After that i evaluated the model. Finally i need to save the model evaluation results to a text file. I am getting an error when i try to write the model evaluation results to a file.

Here is my jar file  :

```
    import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
    import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.FeatureHasher

    import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


    object class1 {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {



          val sc: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[1]")
            .appName("SparkByExample")
            .getOrCreate()



          val df2 = sc.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","sep"->",","header"->"true")).csv(args(0))
        val hasher = new FeatureHasher().setInputCols(Array("x1","x2")).setOutputCol("features")
        val transformed = hasher.transform(df2)

        val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(100).setRegParam(0.1).
setElasticNetParam(0.6).setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("automatic")
        val Array(train, test) = transformed.randomSplit(Array(0.9, 0.1))

        val lrModel = lr.fit(train)
        val result = lrModel.transform(test)

         val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
         evaluator.setLabelCol("automatic")
         evaluator.setMetricName("accuracy")
         val accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(result)

        accuracy.saveAsFiles(args(1))

      }

    }
```

my error is as follows :

```
[error] C:\Spark\src\main\scala\WordCount.scala:39:14: value saveAsFiles is not a member of Double
[error]     accuracy.saveAsFiles(args(1))
[error]              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

This error implied that ,i cannot use  saveAsFiles with a double object.

Can someone help me in understanding how to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`accuracy` is no longer a `DataFrame`. It's just a simple double. You can use regular Scala to save it to a file e.g.

```
Files.write(..., accuracy.toString)
```